# Prove that $\arcsin z = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $\arccos (z) = -i\ln (z + \sqrt{z^2-1})$ and $\arcsin (z)=-i \ln(iz +\sqrt{1-z^2}).$

Now I must prove, that $\arcsin (z) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos (z)$.

I get:

$$\arcsin (z)=-i\ln\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right)=-i\ln\left(iz+\sqrt{-1(z^2-1)}\right)=-i\ln\left(iz+\sqrt{i^{2}(z^2-1)}\right)=$$
$$=-\ln\left(iz+i\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)=-i\ln\left(i(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})\right)=-i\ln -i\ln\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)=$$
$$=-i\left(\ln|i|+i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-i\ln\left(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\arccos (z).$$

I don't know where I make mistake, because I have "+" not "-".

Comment: One hint: $\ln(\sqrt{i^2})$ is not always equal to $\ln(i)$

Comment: so what I do now

Comment: Easiest way would be using $\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}-w\right) = \cos w$.

Comment: but it is multiplicative funkction ... i would do made in this way ..

Comment: someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the statement is true, namely,
\begin{align}
\sin^{-1}(z) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}(z).
\end{align}
By taking the sine of both sides leads to
\begin{align}
\sin(\sin^{-1}(z)) &= \sin(\frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1}(z)) \\
z &= \sin(\pi/2) \cos(\cos^{-1}(z)) - \cos(\pi/2) \sin(\cos^{-1}(z)) \\
z &= z.
\end{align}
This shows the identity is true.

Comment: Well, $\sin \left ( \cos^{-1}(z) - \frac{\pi}{2} \right )$ also equals $z$, but $\sin^{-1}(z) \ne \cos^{-1} (z) - \frac{\pi}{2}$.  In other words, $\sin \vartheta_1 = \sin \vartheta_2$ does not imply $\vartheta_1 = \vartheta_2$.

Comment: This is not a correct proof. The implication $\sin^{-1}(z) = \pi/2 - \cos^{-1}(z) \implies z=z$ is entirely different from the implication $z=z\implies\sin^{-1}(z) = \pi/2 - \cos^{-1}(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

lets start by defining `$w` to be `$sin(w) = z`
now, we'll use the complex identity:

```
sin(w) = z = (exp(iw)-exp(-iw))/2i
```

define `t = exp(iw)` therefor, by applying this to the previous equation:

```
z = (t - 1/t)/2i
```

multiply by `2i` and pass all args to the right side to get:

```
t^2 - (2iz) - 1 = 0
```

a standard quadratic equation:

```
t = ((2iz)+sqrt((2i*z)^2 + 4))/2
t = i*z + sqrt(1 - z^2)
```

but we defined `t = exp(i*w)` therfor:

```
exp(iw) = i*z + sqrt(1 - z^2)
```

take the `log` to both sides and get that:

`iw = log(i*z + sqrt(1 - z^2))` 
divide by `i`:

```
w = (1/i) * log(i*z + sqrt(1 - z^2))
```

but as we first defined: `sin(w) = z` then`w = arcsin(z)`
in total:

```
arcsin(z) = (1/i) * log(i*z + sqrt(1 - z^2))
```

that proves your claim is right.

Comment: Please do not bump old posts unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My usual naive approach.

From
$\arccos (z) = -i\ln (z + \sqrt{z^2-1})
$
and
$\arcsin (z)=-i \ln(iz +\sqrt{1-z^2})
$
we get

$\begin{array}\\
\arccos (z)+\arcsin (z)
&=-i(\ln (z + \sqrt{z^2-1})+\ln(iz +\sqrt{1-z^2}))\\
&=-i(\ln ((z + \sqrt{z^2-1})(iz +\sqrt{1-z^2}))\\
&=-i(\ln ((z + i\sqrt{1-z^2})(iz +\sqrt{1-z^2}))\\
&=-i(\ln (iz^2+z\sqrt{1-z^2}(-1+1)+i(1-z^2))\\
&=-i(\ln (i))\\
&=-i(\dfrac{i\pi}{2})\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

Throw in a $2k\pi i$
if you want.
That will change the answer to
$\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

For $z$ real and $z<1$, draw a right triangle with hypotenuse of length $1$ and a side of length $z$.  Call the angle opposite the side of length $z$, $\alpha$ and the angle adjacent to this side, $\beta$.
Obviously $\alpha + \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ or $$\sin^{-1} z =\frac{\pi}{2} - \cos^{-1} z, \quad (0<z<1).$$

Since the left-hand side and the right-hand side are equal on the segment $0<z<1$, and each has an analytic continuation that is entire, they are equal for all $z$ in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=\arcsin z+\arccos z$. Then $f'(z)=0$ on $(-1,1)$. Hence $f(z)=c$ is constant on $[-1,1]$ by continuity. And also $c=f(-1)=-\frac\pi 2+\pi=\frac\pi 2.$