# Complex Analysis $\arcsin z + \arccos z = \frac\pi2$ proof

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Similar problem was posted here: [Prove that $\arcsin z = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785028/prove-that-arcsin-z-frac-pi2-arccos-z) , and he has the same problem as me but none of the answers actually answered his question. The problem is proving $i\cdot \ln(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}) = - i\cdot \ln(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}) - \pi/2$. Here is my attempt
$$i\cdot \ln(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}) = i \cdot \ln(i(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})$$
$$=i\cdot \ln(i) + i\cdot \ln(z + \sqrt{z^2-1})$$
$$ = -\pi/2 + i\cdot \ln(z + \sqrt{z^2-1})$$
And hence it misses a minus sign in front of the last logarithm.

Comment: You must multiply both sides in a minus.

Comment: Another way is to differentiate the LHS.

Comment: @MyGLasses Multiplying by a minus would also change the LHS, but the LHS as it stands now is correct, so I don't think that'll work? The problem is that there should be a minus in front of the last natural logarithm.

Comment: but in link it has minus, may I wrong @Marius

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $$\arcsin(x)+\arccos(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$ for all $x\in [-1,1]$. (For example try to compute the derivative)

Hence, thanks to the unicity of the holomorphic continuation, you also have the equality for the complex numbers.